# Find the number of solutions of $\ln |\sin x|=-x^2+2x$ when $x\in [0,\pi]$ and when $x\in [-\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

The question can be easily solved by graphing the function. And it isnt particularly difficult to graph them either

However it is difficult to check whether the graphs will intersect or not, and at how many points, without a calculator at our disposal. Are there any methods to check this?

Comment: For the first interval, we know that there is at least two roots since the derivative of $f(x)=\log(\sin(x))+x^2-2x$ is $f'(x)=2 x+\cot (x)-2$ cancels at least one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici what does ‘cancels at least one’ mean?

Comment: Since the derivative cancels once in the range, there is an extremum.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ok you applied LMVT. What about the next interval though?